# segue and EKEventViewController refresh

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I have a `UITableViewController` that push a `EKEventViewController` on selecting a row using this code:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
     if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"eventHandler"]){
         if (_currentPanel.event_identifier != nil) {
             self.event = [[[CalendarHelper sharedInstance] store] eventWithIdentifier:_currentPanel.event_identifier];
    } else {
        EKEventStore *store = [[CalendarHelper sharedInstance] store];
        self.event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        _event.startDate = self.qualifyDate;
        _event.endDate = self.qualifyDate;

        _event.title = @"test identifier" ;
        _event.calendar = [[CalendarHelper sharedInstance] calendar];
    }
    self.eventDatailController =  (EKEventViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

    self.eventDatailController.event = self.event;
    self.eventDatailController.allowsEditing = YES;
    self.eventDatailController.allowsCalendarPreview = YES;
    self.eventDatailController.delegate = self;
}
}
```

The Event show well but after editing the event in `EKEventViewController` through the Edit button and finishing tapping Done button, the event in `EKEventViewController` is not accordingly refreshed.

The `SimpleEKDemo` works fine but doesn't use

```
prepareForSegue:sender:
```

but

```
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always call the prepareForSegue method from didSelectRowAtIndexPath by just doing:

```
[self prepareForSegue:@"EKEventViewController" sender:self];
```